# como recuperar un modulo y userform de VBA en excel despues de cerrar

Tags: excel, vba

Llevo semanas trabajando en un archivo de excel con un userForm, justo ahora lo guarde y al cerrarlo y volverlo abrir(unos minutos despues) la macro que lo abria me dice que no se puede ejecutar la macro, puede que no este disponible o se han desabilitado. Al ir a la pestaña de programador visual basic el modulo y el formulario desaparecieron, no estan en el arbol despegable como si nunca hubieran existido.. Como lo puedo recuperar?

Nota; todas las macros estan activadas en el centro de confianza

Comment: ¿Porque no agregar lo que has intentado, el código ? revisar [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has perdido dicho código. Precisamente cuando estás programando en VBA, en tu caso en Excel, dichos archivos se deben de guardar con formato XLSM, es decir, un "Libro de Excel habilitado para macros", al hacerlo, Excel te garantiza que almacenará los Proyectos de VB (tu código como tal); al respecto cuando lo intentas guardar sin la habilitación de macros, el mismo Excel te hace la advertencia de que si insistes en guardarlo sin esta habilitación, no se almacenarán tales Proyectos de VB. En tu caso, creo que hiciste caso omiso a esa advertencia, y por lo tanto tu valioso código, producto de varios días de esfuerzo, lo has perdido. No me gusta ser portador de malas noticias, sin embargo espero que puedas rehacer tu código y asegúrate de guardarlos en el formato correcto para que no sufras de una nueva perdida de código fuente.